# Php & Mysql , How to get the details of a medical record from Tables Patients and Medical_Record?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm wondering about How I can write a function to get some parameters from a database.

I have to get the medical record of some patients, I have two tables

Table 1: "Patients"
idpatient int (10) Primarykey
names
age
id_card

and 
Table 2: "Medical_record"
id_medical int (10) Primarykey
date
id_patient
diagnostic

How can I do to join those tables and get the details of every patient and record..for example if I select a patient called Jhon, I would like to see the details of everytime he was in the hospital, showing table like this, using php and mysql.

**desired output**

```
Id:0001
Name:Jhon J.
Date ---- --------Diagnostic 
10/05/2012        headache
15/04/2013        stomache
28/08/2014        some stuff
```

**function**

```
public function look_assign($idPatient, $idRecord){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM patients WHERE idpatients = '".$idpatient."' AND idRecord = '".$idRecord."' ";
    $this->result = $this->objDb->select($query);
    return $this->result;

}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You must make a join request, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT
                        p.*, mr.*
                    FROM patients p
                    INNER JOIN medical_record mr ON p.idpatients = mr.id_patient
                    WHERE p.idpatients = '".$idpatient."' AND p.idRecord = '".$idRecord."' ";
```

Comment: How can I get a record for every a single patient? I've tried doing it with php , altouhg I think the query is alrigth to get it but I do not know How to show that table.